# Meteor.userId() null inside a package

Tags: meteor, package, account

I am creating a meteor package. This package has use of`account-base` in  `package.json`.

I have created a method on server side like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
    hide: function(notification_id){
        kahonNotification.hide(notification_id,Meteor.userId())
    }    
});
```

The problem is that Meteor.userId() is null all time.

here is the configuration package.json file:

```
Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.0.5');
  api.use(['standard-app-packages'], ['client','server']);
  api.use('accounts-base', 'server');

  // Allows the user of this package to choose their own Bootstrap
  // implementation.
  api.use(['twbs:bootstrap@3.3.1', 'nemo64:bootstrap@3.3.1_1'], 'client', {weak: true});

  api.addFiles(['client/notifications.html','client/notifications.js'],'client');
  api.addFiles(['server/main.js','server/publications.js'],'server');
  api.addFiles('shared/collections.js',['server','client'])

  api.imply(['templating'], 'client');
  api.export('kahonNotification')

});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('kahon:notificationsefficient');
  api.addFiles('notificationsefficient-tests.js');
});
```

Comment: As soon as the question is answered and you've done the solution commit, the question becomes worthless. Any future reader just won't be able to benefit of it. Please post HERE the code associated with your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not logged in the web page. It is the solution.